# What factors should I consider when granting an electorate?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I'm playing as Austria, Emperor of the HRE, and one of the electors was recently fully annex by a neighbouring state. I can now choose to replace them, and grant another state in the HRE the status of elector (allowing them to choose the next emperor).

What factors should I consider in my decision to choose a new elector. Obviously a nation that has good relations with me now is more likely to vote for me in the short term, but are there any long-term effects I should watch out for (nations with the potential for expansion, weak nations, strong nations, nations that border me, etc.)? Or, are there good reasons for not choosing a new elector at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I'd recommend. First, a small country is always good, because you can have a pretty strong hold on them. One province minors are particularly useful. I would recommend you have an alliance and royal marriage with them, because, aside from the relations bonus, alliances give you a +50 score and royal marriages give you a +10 score. Also, you should probably guarantee their independence in order to prevent them from being conquered. Also related to that, try to find a nation that is within the middle of the HRE, nations on the borders, especially the border with France, are much more likely to be picked off. The last thing that can help to make them loyal to you is to make sure they're part of the same culture group as you, which gives a +5 bonus.

Answer (score 3):

Another consideration is beating an OPM out of someone and giving it an electorate - the +100 relations from releasing it in peace deal lasts quite a while and will insure you have its vote for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I would first secure an alliance, marriage(if applicable) and vassalage if possible. This allows you to "rig" the elections in your favor. As long as you know that nation will vote for you i don't think you need to worry about those sort of things with a few exceptions. Choosing smaller nations closer to you is my personal preference acting as a "big brother" sort of figure. Nations that border can cause the relationship effect "Border Conflict/Border Tension" which can negatively affect a nation. But if the nation hold none HRE lands and expands for more none HRE land i wouldn't chose said nation because it is a high possibility of it "blobbing" which places them as a HRE ruler contender. @me if you need clarification.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend vassalage. Though it gives you a +50 score when that elector is making their decision, it also gives a -50 score with all other electors...so unless you plan to vassalize a bunch of electors really quickly, not a good move.

Comment: In addition, having vassal electors reduces imperial authority by 0.1 per subjugated elector per month - which also prevents the passive increase of IA. If you plan to reform the HRE, you are better off choosing a small OPM of your culture and religion, as others mentioned.